# What does "put out someone's joint" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, lyrics

While listening to "Furious" by Jade Bird, I found a line I don't fully understand.

The lyrics:

> When did you make up your mind?
>   When did you decide to let me down?
>   When was the turning point?
>   **When you put out your joint and you laid her down**
>   [...]

What does the part "put out your joint" mean?

The second piece "laid her down" is ambiguous to me as well.
It can be either "he killed her" or "he satisfied her sexually".
It is likely the latter, though.

Any help would be welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's lyrics interpretation / Lit Crit

Comment: @FumbleFingers why are questions with lyrics deemed to be off-topic?

Comment: Because the meaning of lyrics / poetry / etc. is often vague / ambiguous, and the constructions themselves often involve creative one-off usages. It seems likely to me the "joint" in question is a marijuana cigarette (singer's unfaithful boyfriend got stoned and gave in to the temptation of sex with another girl), but anything I might say about that is just my opinion. In other contexts, *to put out one's joint* might mean something completely different (such as *to dislocate one's shoulder*) - so this is all about *interpretation*, not the words themselves.

Comment: Note that the site guidelines themselves don't explicitly exclude lyrics interpretation - that's just ***my opinion***. But honestly, no normal native Anglophone would say anything like *When did you lay her down?* when challenging a partner about his unfaithfulness, so it's really not the kind of usage you should want to learn unless you're planning to become a (bad) poet in a foreign language.

Comment: No reason to close just because it's a poem or a lyric *if the question is about the possible literal meanings* or syntax, etc etc.

Comment: Why would you think "laid her down" means he killed her? A boxer might "lay someone out" meaning to knock them unconscious ... You might "lay a person to rest," meaning to bury them at a funeral ... But I can't think of a usage where it means actually killing someone. FumbleFingers' interpretation above sounds accurate, w/o knowing more about the song. Smoking pot w/some other girl, he puts out the cigarette & then ... Also, I'd say it seems the confusion doesn't stem from lyrical/poetic construction or grammar as much as slang/vernacular vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To put out a joint** can mean to snuff out a marijuana cigarette.

**to lay *something* down** literally means to place it down on a surface.

> He laid his pen down on the desk.

**to lay *someone* down** means to place (or guide) the person into a supine position.

> He carried her across the room and laid her down on the bed.